# How to add a fade-in effect in jQuery text

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to add a fade-in effect when the data is returned to the `#results` div?

```
$('#results').html(data);
```

I tried

```
$('#results').html(data).fadeIn('slow');
```

but it doesn't seem to work

My code

```
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            // do other stuff for a valid form
            $.post('mailme.php', $("#myform").serialize(), function(data) {
                $('#results').html(data).fadeIn('slow');
            });
        }
```

Comment: Post your full page code here, with css.

Comment: @abdulwakeel is this the reason of the down vote ?

Comment: maybe you just need to hide it first

Comment: Whoops, i have vote up, not down, its was -1 already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You gotta hide the div first.

```
$('#results').hide().html(data).fadeIn('slow');
```

Answer (score 0):

This might just do the trick.

```
$('#results').css('display', 'none').html(data).fadeIn('slow');
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to hide element firstly when you are working with "fadeIn".

here is a example, I believe you will understand after trying and editing that:

```
<img style="display: none;" id="google" src="http://www.google.com.tr/images/srpr/logo3w.png" alt="" />

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#google').fadeIn(1200,function(){});
    });
</script>
```